# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname' (111)

Tags: mysql, networking, centos

Thanks in advance for your help.

I am facing an issue with mysql server which is the title of this topic, by using the command:

```
mysql -u myuser -pmypass -h `hostname`  db_name
```

I get the error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'hostname' (111)
```

So I checked the *my.cnf* file and I have no lines with "bind address" and "skip-networking" although I tried adding them and restarting which did not change anything.

Besides that there is no error in the sql logs, and we can (with HeidiSQL) connect to the server remotely knowing that the user is `myuser"@"%`. Mysql listens on the port 3306, so it's ok there

Also, users created with with @'localhost', works fine with the command line (without the -h option).

What is more intriguing is that other servers that look exactly the same work both locally and remotely with the first command...

The server runs with CentOS 6.2

So if anyone has an idea on this matter I would be glad to hear it

P.S : It's my first time posting here, so if there are formatting issues, please forgive me

Comment: `hostname` is passed literally? If yes, replace it with the address of your server (or `localhost`)

Comment: No it is passed between "grave accent" (thus it is the unix command that is executed)

Answer (score 7):

Simply check your my.cnf and change from

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

to

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

if you don't have that parameter just add it.

Binding to the 0.0.0.0 let your mysql being available on every IP configured cause you can't bind just on two or three IP on the server, the config can be: localhost or everything.

Then check your /etc/hosts file and be sure that the line

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

contains also your server hostname, as example: my hostname is "db01", my /etc/hosts is

```
127.0.0.1 localhost db01
```

Keep in mind that after the install process via yum (I don't know if CentOS do this automagically for you, I just know that Gentoo does not) you have to execute mysql_install_db and then configure the password for the root user, be absolutely sure that you'd set up a password for:

```
'root'@'localhost'
'root'@'hostname'
'root'@'127.0.0.1'
'root'@'%'
```

(for security issue be also sure to remove from mysql.user those entry with user='')

hope this helps

Answer (score 4):

Belated response, but I believe that error message means that the server you are trying to connect to is not listening on that interface.

If you change the config to:

`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`

as suggested above, what you are doing is configuring the server to reject all connections except those from localhost (itself).

`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

is in most cases sufficient, and makes mysql listen on all interfaces on the system, which makes it accessible via all the addresses that the host is accessible at.

Answer (score 0):

Enable port on firewall and try...

in terminal,
execute commands as `root`.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3306/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score -2):

There is a reason I met that You MySQL server's **IP address conflict** with other server in your local network.